# Play full music to Unlogged Users using Deezer API

Tags: javascript, api, stream, deezer

I have a website and it includes the option for users to search and listen to music using the Deezer API. It works fine, however, when the user is not logged in, the songs have a limit of 30 seconds. I've found [this section](http://developers.deezer.com/guidelines#levels) in Deezer documentation that explains the music access to unlogged users:

> 30s clips listening restrictions.

But, I would like to make the full songs available to all users of my website to listen to, so is there any paid way or partnership with Deezer to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for your users to stream full tracks on Deezer is that they are users from our service and logged in.